# In BGE, can you make an objects animation only play when that object is in motion?

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

How can I make an object's animation only play when that object is moving?
I do not need it to play on mouse press, only when's it's moving.

Answer (score 1):

Well, make a Mouse sensor, and controller and action actuator and connect them together. Set the mouse sensor to what you need(for example, left button with true level triggering) and action actuator to your action! So simple!;)

Comment: he does NOT want it to play on mouse press, only when the character is moving. However the question is worded so poorly I can't tell if that is really what he wants.

Comment: Well than he can use python to get object's linear velocity and than, activate action if the object's linear velocity is higher than 0! But in that case he need to move object using force or linear velocity!